# Passing of arrays from Beans

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have this code in my JSP.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="9">
var g=<jsp:getProperty name="header" property="apn[i]" />;
```

And my bean has getters and setters for

```
String[] apn = new String[10];
```

When I run my JSP, I am getting this error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Cannot find any information on property 'apn[i]' in a bean of type 'com.Bean.DetailsBean'.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JSP EL to access the array.

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="9">
var g=${header.apn[i]}
```

I'm not sure you want the effect this will create however, since its going to create 9 `g` variables in the global scope.

Comment: I am getting this error "The method Configure(HttpServletResponse) is undefined for the type DetailsBean"

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the version of for loop without range:

```
<c:forEach items="${header.apn}" var="apn">
    <c:out value="${apn}" />
</c:forEach>
```

For this, you don't have to know the size of the array. And hard-coding the begin and end indices is a bad idea IMHO.